# How can read files from directory using R?

Tags: r

What I need to do is read in all files with `*.json` from multiple folders and store the results in a `data.table`

I have a folder named `ROOT` that contains two folders `A` and `B`. The `A` and `B` also contain folders from `A` to `Z` where the `*json` files are located.

how can do this with a lot of folders inside each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
list.files(path = "c:/users/YOURNAMEGOESHERE/documents", pattern = "json", recursive = TRUE)
```

first change the path to the folder you want. For example, in MS Windows, change `YOURNAMEGOESHERE` to your own name, or whatever is appropriate.  The argument `recursive` allows the search to be done in all subfolders.